# Random Images on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, random, each

I am currently building a site whereby they would like each image on load to display different images. I have so far been able to target these and randomise them but it is applying the same image to all of the items. If you could see where I'm going wrong it would be great

```
var description = [
  "http://placehold.it/300x300",
  "http://placehold.it/200x200",
  "http://placehold.it/100x100"
];

var size = description.length
var x = Math.floor(size*Math.random())

$('.item img').each(function() {

    if($("img").hasClass("people")) {
        $(this).attr("src",description[x]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be 2 problems with your code:

1. Your randomizer is outside the `.each` loop. Hence why all your images get the same image.
2. All images get the src attribute, even those without the `people` class.

You nearly got it right though. Try a [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/e2f9f96z/) I made with these corrections, or the demo below.

```js
var description = [
  "http://placehold.it/300x300",
  "http://placehold.it/200x200",
  "http://placehold.it/100x100"
];

var size = description.length;
$('.item img').each(function() {
  var x = Math.floor(size * Math.random()); //move random inside loop
  if ($(this).hasClass("people")) { //replace "img" with "this"
    $(this).attr("src", description[x]);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <img src="" class="people">
</div>
<div class="item">
  <img src="" class="people">
</div>
<div class="item">
  <img src="">
</div>
<div class="item">
  <img src="" class="people">
</div>
```

Note that there are 4 `items` here, but one is without the `people` class and correctly isn't set to an image (only 3 are).

Answer (score 3):

`x` does not change. You can use `setTimeout()` within `$.each()` to push random element of array to an array without duplicates; utilize selector `$(".item img.people")` set `<img>` `src` with `.attr(function)` which iterates all elements in collection of original selector

```js
var description = [
  "http://placehold.it/300x300",
  "http://placehold.it/200x200",
  "http://placehold.it/100x100"
];

var arr = [];

$.each(description,
  function(i, el) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      arr.push(el);
      if (arr.length === description.length) {
        $(".item img.people")
          .attr("src", function(i, src) {
            return arr[i]
          })
      }
    }, 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5))
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="item">
  <img class="people" alt="">
  <img class="people" alt="">
  <img class="people" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not define random number globally. May be below code will help you.

```
var description = [
  "http://placehold.it/300x300",
  "http://placehold.it/200x200",
  "http://placehold.it/100x100"
];

var size = description.length;
var x=0;

$('.item img').each(function() {
   x = Math.floor(size*Math.random());

  if($(this).hasClass("people")) {
       $(this).attr("src",description[x]);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some error in your code. you define `if($("img".` and that check the first `img` but you want each img

```
var description = [
  "http://placehold.it/300x300",
  "http://placehold.it/200x200",
  "http://placehold.it/100x100"
];

var size = description.length

$('.item img').each(function(i,e) {
   var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * size)
    if($(this).hasClass("people")) {
        $(this).attr("src",description[x]);
    }
});
```