# Text content randomising on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, math, random

I have a site whereby I have different boxes with certain content that when the user refreshes the content will need to randomise in different boxes every time. Basically when you refresh, the content randomises.

So far I have managed to randomise images on load with similar code([Random Images on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993152/random-images-on-page-load)), but for some reason when attempting this for html it doesn't inject the data where I am saying for it to go, as when you refresh the page different areas populate with different text. When pasting into console to text it just lists out the object array. If you could point out where I have gone wrong that would be great. HTML and Script is below.

```js
var text_boxes = [{
  number: "2",
  sub_title: "Marketers",
}, {
  number: "75%",
  sub_title: "Average sales increase",
}, {
  number: "4",
  sub_title: "Developers",
}, {
  number: "6",
  sub_title: "Full Time",
}, {
  number: "45",
  sub_title: "Sites Launched",
}, {
  number: "2",
  sub_title: "Marketers",
}];

var arr3 = [];

$.each(text_boxes,
  function(i, el) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      arr3.push(el);
      if (arr3.length === text_boxes.length) {
        $(".item").hasClass(".text", function(i) {
          $(this).next('.has-text').find('.number span').text(arr3[i].number);
          $(this).next('.has-text').find('.sub-title span').text(arr3[i].sub_title);
        });
      }
    }, 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5));
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item small has-text small-offset-large">
  <div class="inner">
    <a href="" class="">
      <div class="text">
        <div class="title number">
          <span>2</span>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-title">
          <span>Marketers</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item small small secondary has-text test">
 <div class="inner">
  <a href="" class="">
   <div class="text">
    <div class="title">
     <span>Test</span>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-title">
     <span>Test</span>
    </div>
   </div>
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.hasClass(".text"` should be `.hasClass("text"`. Now this method doesn't accept any callback method, so anyway this won't loop.

Comment: How would I be able to get this to now loop? I now keep getting an error in console of "number" being undefined @A.Wolff

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help you. For me is not clear what is your goal.

```js
var text_boxes = [{
    number: "2",
    sub_title: "Marketers",
}, {
    number: "75%",
    sub_title: "Average sales increase",
}, {
    number: "4",
    sub_title: "Developers",
}, {
    number: "6",
    sub_title: "Full Time",
}, {
    number: "45",
    sub_title: "Sites Launched",
}, {
    number: "2",
    sub_title: "Marketers",
}];

$.each($(".item"), function() {
  var $item = $(this);
  $.each(text_boxes, function(i, el) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        if($item.find('div.text').length) {
          $item.find('.number span').text(text_boxes[i].number);
          $item.find('.sub-title span').text(text_boxes[i].sub_title);
        }
     }, i * 1000);
   });
});
```

```css
div.item {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item small has-text small-offset-large">
    <div class="inner">
        <a href="" class="">
            <div class="text">
                <div class="title number">
                    <span>2</span>
                </div>
                <div class="sub-title">
                    <span>Marketers</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="item small has-text small-offset-large">
    <div class="inner">
        <a href="" class="">
            <div class="text">
                <div class="title number">
                    <span>2</span>
                </div>
                <div class="sub-title">
                    <span>Marketers</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="item small has-text small-offset-large">
    <div class="inner">
        <a href="" class="">
            <div class="text">
                <div class="title number">
                    <span>2</span>
                </div>
                <div class="sub-title">
                    <span>Marketers</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```